# Как умножить все числа в тексте на другое число разом?

Tags: java, c++, автоматизация

Помогите решить задачу, вручную умножать каждое число будет долго, какой код можно написать, чтобы быстро решить его? Нет идей..

Слабый набросок накидал на С++:

```
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void convertFromTo(char* ch, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (ch[i] >= '0' && ch[i] <= '9') {
            //собрать число в int умножить и оставить результат в массиве
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int size = 100000;
    char* word = new char[size];
    cin.getline(word, 100000);
    int len = strlen(word);
    convertFromTo(word, len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cout << word[i];
    }
    delete[] word;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [man strtoll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) вам в помощь. (Читаете строку и сканируете ее в цикле, вызывая `strtoll()`)

Comment: Так нужно умножать каждый символ-цифру в строке на некое число: "12 34" -> [N,2N, 3N, 4N]?  Или определить _числа_ из нескольких цифр: "12 34" и домножать уже их -> [12N, 34N]?